# Why is $\lambda\mapsto(\lambda\textbf{1}-T)^{-1}$ analytic on $\rho(T)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, spectral-theory

Let $T$ be a (closed) linear operator on a Banach space $X$. Denote by $\rho(T)$ the resolvent set of $T$, namely, $$\rho(T)=\{\lambda \in \mathbb{C}:(\lambda\textbf{1}-T)^{-1} \in B(X)\},$$ where $B(X)$ denotes the set of bounded linear operators of $X$ onto $X$.

I am trying to figure out why the mapping $\lambda\mapsto(\lambda\textbf{1}-T)^{-1}$ is analytic on $\rho(T)$.

Can anyone please give me an explanation or point to towards a good reference that shows why this is true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us denote (as usual) the resolvent operator by $R(\lambda,T)$, hence $R(\lambda,T)=(\lambda\textbf{1}-T)^{-1}$. For $\lambda, \mu \in \rho(T)$ with $ \lambda \ne \mu $ one has the Resolvent Equation

$\frac{R(\lambda,T)-R(\mu,T)}{\lambda - \mu}=-R(\lambda,T) \cdot R(\mu,T)$, therefore

$ \lim_{\lambda \to \mu}\frac{R(\lambda,T)-R(\mu,T)}{\lambda - \mu}=-R(\mu,T)^2$.

Comment: My apologies for resurrecting such an old question, but upon closer inspection, I realized that taking the limit in the last line assumes that $(\lambda\textbf{1}-T)^{-1}$ is continuous in $\lambda$. How do we know this is true in, say, the case where $T$ is unbounded?

Comment: @DJS I'm wondering about this too - see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2818085

Comment: @TomCollinge - I managed to find an answer to the question. Please see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/294002/reference-request-the-resolvent-is-analytic-in-the-resolvent-set/294015?noredirect=1#comment735162_294015

Comment: @DJS. Thanks. I got a comment completely resolving my question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2818085